# How to build an API as a plugin

Tags: plugins, php, api

I want to create a REST API endpoint for a wordpress site where I can get a JSON response for different queries. I have tried the tutorial [here](http://coderrr.com/create-an-api-endpoint-in-wordpress/), but I cant seem to figure out how it works. Do I need to register all the query variables to use them? Also I think it would be best to use the `add_rewrite_endpoint` but I have not used any of this before. So I would like to know how to use that function in the code below.

I want to send a query like `<url>/wp-api/version` where it will return the wordpress version number. But right now its not taking any queries other than 'pugs'. I am not sure what exactly is going on with the regex so I didn't change that. Can someone please help me understand this?

```
class WP_API_Endpoint{

//  Hook WordPress
public function __construct(){
    add_filter('query_vars', array($this, 'add_query_vars'), 0);
    add_action('parse_request', array($this, 'sniff_requests'), 0);
    add_action('init', array($this, 'add_endpoint'), 0);
}   

/*  
    Add public query vars
    @param array $vars List of current public query vars
    @return array $vars     
*/
public function add_query_vars($vars){
    $vars[] = '__wp-api';
    $vars[] = 'pugs';
    return $vars;
}

//  Add API Endpoint
public function add_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_rule('^wp-api/pugs/?([0-9]+)?/?','index.php?__wp-api=1&pugs=$matches[1]','top');
}

/*  
    Sniff Requests
    This is where we hijack all API requests
    If $_GET['__api'] is set, we kill WP and serve our data
    @return die if API request
*/
public function sniff_requests(){
    global $wp;
    if(isset($wp->query_vars['__wp-api'])){
        $this->handle_request();
        exit;
    }
}

protected function get_wp_version() {
    return get_bloginfo('version');
}

//  This is where we handle incoming requests
protected function handle_request(){

    global $wp;

    $pugs = $wp->query_vars['pugs'];
    if($pugs)
        $this->send_response('wp-version', $this->get_wp_version());
    else
        $this->send_response('Something went wrong with the pug bomb factory');

}

//  This sends a JSON response to the browser
protected function send_response($key, $val){
    $response[$key] = $val;
    header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    echo json_encode($response)."\n";
    exit;
}
}
new WP_API_Endpoint();
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing is the add rewrite rule function. You have -

```
add_rewrite_rule('^wp-api/pugs/?([0-9]+)?/?','index.php?__wp-api=1&pugs=$matches[1]','top');
```

`wp-api/pugs/?([0-9]+)` this means, when you request `<url>/wp-api/pugs/123`, you will get a query variable pugs with parameter **123**.

```
$var = get_query_var('pugs'); // = 123
```

Now, you don't really need **pugs** in the url as per you needs. So, just remove it this way. Also, the matching regex should not be number only. so the changed code would be -

```
add_rewrite_rule('^wp-api/?([^/]+)?/?','index.php?__wp-api=1&pugs=$matches[1]','top');
```

Final usage is:

```
protected function handle_request(){

    global $wp;

    $pugs = $wp->query_vars['pugs'];

    // <url>/wp-api/version/
    if( 'version' == $pugs )
        $this->send_response( 'wp-version', $this->get_wp_version() );


    // <url>/wp-api/something/
    elseif( 'something' == $pugs )
        $this->send_response( 'something', 'something' );

    else
        $this->send_response( 'Something went wrong with the pug bomb factory');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it out a bit. Why do we still want pugs in the second parameter of `add_rewrite_rule`? and then on `query_vars['pugs']`?

Comment: Here `pugs` stands for the variable name. You can replace it to something else on both location. For example, you can call it `myparameter`, then it would be `myparameter=$matches[1]` and `$my_parameter = $wp->query_vars['myparameter'];`